# Using JS variable in ERB

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a dropdown list of patients:

```
<%= form_for @assessment do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
       <%= f.select :patient, content_tag(:option,'select patient...',:value=>"")+content_tag(:option,'New Patient',:value=>"")+options_from_collection_for_select(@patients, 'id', 'full_name'), :class=>"form-control" %><br />
    </div>
```

When a patient from the dropdown is selected, I use Jquery to get the id of the selected patient:

```
<script>
  $('#assessment_patient').change(function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("assessment_patient");
    var patient_id = (e.options[e.selectedIndex].value)
  });
 </script>
```

I want to pass said patient_id in a link_to rails helper:

```
 <%= link_to template.name, {:controller => "assessments", :action => "new", :template_id => template.id, :patient_id => patient_id, :remote=> true }%>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I use my JS variable in ERB? Or can I pass Jquery selector in link_to ?

Answer (score 1):

ERB is parsed and processed on the server. JavaScript on your web page is parsed and executed in the browser. By the time there's a JavaScript value, ERB processing has already happened. So you can't read JavaScript values directly in ERB because they don't yet exist as no JavaScript has been executed.

If you are trying to inject the JavaScript value into the DOM somewhere, you can do so with JavaScript rather than trying to do it with ERB. If, on the other hand, you need the JavaScript value on the server (for example, if you have to use it as part of a database query), you can try an option like sending it via XHR/AJAX.